# Raycast Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Command. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, raycast

I'm having the following problem:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Command. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useState                   useState
4. useRef                     useEffect
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at Command (/Users/userName/.config/raycast/extensions/server/index.js:7619:52)
    at Fr (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:9:2490)
    at ray-navigation-stack
    at Vo (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:9:2088)
    at Suspense
    at Er (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:8:968)
    at ray-root
    at fi (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:9:3000)
10:02:20.911 The above error occurred in the <Command> component:

    at Command (/Users/userName/.config/raycast/extensions/server/index.js:7619:52)
    at Fr (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:9:2490)
    at ray-navigation-stack
    at Vo (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:9:2088)
    at Suspense
    at Er (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:8:968)
    at ray-root
    at fi (/Applications/Raycast.app/Contents/Resources/RaycastCommands_RaycastCommands.bundle/Contents/Resources/api/node_modules/@raycast/api/index.js:9:3000)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, InternalErrorBoundary.
10:02:20.912 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Fr:index.js:9:2490
    at ray-navigation-stack
Vo:index.js:9:2088
```

The problem is due to this part:

```js
  const a = Test({ path: defaultDirectory, cmd });
  console.log(`${a}`)
```

Code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Icon, MenuBarExtra, getPreferenceValues } from "@raycast/api";
import { useCachedPromise, showFailureToast } from "@raycast/utils";
import { exec as execCb } from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";
import fs from "fs/promises";

const exec = promisify(execCb);

import { Test } from './test';

interface Preferences {
  defaultDirectory: string;
}

interface Command {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

function convertCommands(commands: { [key: string]: string }): Command[] {
  return Object.entries(commands).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));
}

export default function Command() {
  const preferences = getPreferenceValues<Preferences>();
  const { defaultDirectory } = preferences;
  const [cmd, setCmd] = useState("");

  const a = Test({ path: defaultDirectory, cmd });
  console.log(`${a}`)

  const { isLoading, data, error } = useCachedPromise<Command[]>(async () => {
    console.log("useCachedPromise")
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(
      `find ${defaultDirectory}/package.json -exec echo -n "{}: " \\;`,
    );

    if (stderr) {
      showFailureToast(stderr);
      throw new Error(stderr);
    }

    const files = stdout.split(": ").filter((file) => file.trim() !== "");
    let result = await Promise.all(
      files.map(async (file) => {
        const content = await fs.readFile(file, "utf-8");
        const json = JSON.parse(content);
        return json.scripts;
      }),
    );

    return convertCommands(result[0]);
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  return (
    <MenuBarExtra icon={Icon.Anchor} isLoading={isLoading}>
      <MenuBarExtra.Item title="Script" />
      {data?.map((el: Command) => (
        <MenuBarExtra.Item
          key={el.name}
          title={el.name}
          onAction={() => setCmd(el.name)}
        />
      ))}
    </MenuBarExtra>
  );
}
```

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ChildProcess, exec } from "child_process";
import { shellEnv } from "shell-env";

interface EnvType {
  env: Record<string, string>;
  cwd: string;
  shell: string;
}

let cachedEnv: null | EnvType = null;

const getCachedEnv = async () => {
  if (cachedEnv) {
    return cachedEnv;
  }

  const env = await shellEnv();

  cachedEnv = {
    env: env,
    cwd: env.HOME || `/Users/${process.env.USER}`,
    shell: env.SHELL,
  };
  return cachedEnv;
};

const Test = ({ path, cmd }: { path: string; cmd: string }) => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState<string>("");
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState<boolean>(false);

  console.log("cmd: ", cmd);
  if (cmd === "") return null;
  const ex = `cd ${path} && yarn ${cmd}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    let killed = false;
    let child: ChildProcess | null = null;

    const runCommand = async () => {
      const execEnv = await getCachedEnv();
      console.log("a", execEnv);

      child = exec(ex, execEnv);
      child.stderr?.on("data", (data: string) => {
        if (killed) {
          return;
        }
        setOutput((out) => `${out}${data}`);
      });
      child.stdout?.on("data", (data: string) => {
        if (killed) {
          return;
        }
        setOutput((out) => `${out}${data}`);
      });
      child.on("exit", () => {
        console.log(0);
        if (killed) {
          console.log(1);
          return;
        }
        console.log(2);
        setFinished(true);
      });
    };

    const cleanup = () => {
      killed = true;
      console.log(3);
      if (child !== null) {
        console.log(4);
        child.kill("SIGTERM");
      }
    };

    runCommand();

    return cleanup;
  }, [cmd, setOutput, setFinished]);

  return [output, finished];
};

export { Test };
```

Can you give me a hand?